# Mostrar formulario dependiendo de que botón pulses

Tags: php

estoy con un problema que no consigo resolver.
Tengo una tabla con diferentes registros y una columna con un botón de "ver" para cada una de las listas. Me gustaría saber como puedo abrir un formulario cuando pulso dicho botón "ver" que muestre los datos dependiendo de en que fila este de la tabla.
Es decir que cuando pulse al botón "ver" de la fila "media" se muestre un formulario (que esta oculto) con los datos de "media" y si pulso el de "redes" salga el mismo formulario pero con los datos de "redes"
Los datos los he introducido desde la bd y los botones "ver" se generar automáticamente en el bucle mientras hayan registros que añadir a la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!

Comment: algo que no me queda claro es de donde obtendrias esos datos es decir d e una base de datos o de donde ? para mostrar en c/u de los formularios respectivos...

Answer (score 1):

Saludos lo que podrias hacer es con **Javascript** o **Jquery**, por defecto tener definio un form y ocultarlo algo asi:

```
<form action="" id="myForm" style="display:none">
<div id="contenidoForm"></div>
</form>
```

bien ahora desde donde invoco a una función de **JavaScript** para que controle lo que mostrara seria desde tu tabla:

```
<table border=1>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Utilizar</th>
    <th>Acción</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Redes</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><button onclick="mostrarForm('redes');">Ver</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Media</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><button onclick="mostrarForm('media');">Ver</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

la funcion que invoca es:

```
function mostrarForm(opcion){
  //obtengo el formulario
    form = document.getElementById('myForm');
  //obtengo el div donde colocare el contenido dimanico
  divContenido = document.getElementById('contenidoForm');
  if(opcion == 'redes'){
    //muestro el formulario
        form.style.display='block';
    TITULO = '<h3>ReDeS</h3>';
    //agrego contenido al div
    divContenido.innerHTML =TITULO;
  }
  if(opcion == 'media'){
    //muestro el formulario
        form.style.display='block';
    TITULO = '<h3>MeDiA</h3>';
    //agrego contenido al div
    divContenido.innerHTML =TITULO;
  }
}//end function mostrarForm
```

bien puedes probarlo asi:

```js
function mostrarForm(opcion){
  //obtengo el formulario
 form = document.getElementById('myForm');
  //obtengo el div donde colocare el contenido dimanico
  divContenido = document.getElementById('contenidoForm');
  if(opcion == 'redes'){
   //muestro el formulario
   form.style.display='block';
    TITULO = '<h3>ReDeS</h3>';
    //agrego contenido al div
    divContenido.innerHTML =TITULO;
  }
  if(opcion == 'media'){
   //muestro el formulario
   form.style.display='block';
    TITULO = '<h3>MeDiA</h3>';
    //agrego contenido al div
    divContenido.innerHTML =TITULO;
  }
}//end function mostrarForm
```

```html
<table border=1>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Utilizar</th>
    <th>Acción</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Redes</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><button onclick="mostrarForm('redes');">Ver</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Media</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><button onclick="mostrarForm('media');">Ver</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<BR></BR>
<form action="" id="myForm" style="display:none">
<div id="contenidoForm"></div>
</form>
```

Espero te sirva como base o guia..suerte..!!